# The meaning of ～がいい

Tags: verbs, imperatives, role-language, 連体形

I've read a lot of mangas and I've noticed the use of **がいい** after a verb
e.g.

見る{みる}がいい。

諦めた{あきらめた}ほうがいい。

Does it work as an adverb?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e%e3%81%ae%e8%be%9e%e6%9b%b8%e5%bd%a2-%e3%81%8c%e3%82%88%e3%81%84-how-is-this-allowed In your second example, ほう is not a verb, though

Comment: したほうがいい means "had better".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, 見る and 諦めた方 are grammatically *subjects*, not *adverbs* in those sentences. Words marked with が should be nouns, of course.

As you know, `noun + がいい` (lit. "～ is good", with exhaustive-listing *ga*) is usually used when you choose one thing from a few possible options.

> 「ラーメンとカレー、どっちがいい？」「ラーメンがいい。」

If you want to use this with two or more possible actions (verbs), you normally need a **nominalizer**, which can turn verbs into nouns:

> 「寝る**の**と遊びに行く**の**、どっちがいい？」「寝る**の**がいい。」

Alternatively, you can use 方【ほう】, which is a **noun**. ほう literally means something like "side", but it has many usages, including comparing two or more options. See: [What is 方 used for (when attached to a た-verb)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6525/5010) and [This usage of 方 confuses me](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15321/5010)

> - 本を書く**ほう**がいい。 I like writing books (rather than doing something else). / You should write a book about it.
> - ラーメン**のほう**がいい。 （≒ラーメンがいい）

---

What I've explained so far is about modern, standard Japanese grammar. However, `dictionary-form + がいい` existed in classic Japanese, and is still in use in some rare cases. This is one way of giving an order. (To be precise, this verb form is [連体形](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb#Japanese), which was slightly different from the dictionary form in classic Japanese) See: [<動詞の辞書形>　+　がよい ―　How is this allowed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/5010)

> - 見るがいい！ (≒"Behold!")
> - 諦めるがいい！

Note that this is a very pompous way of speaking, and no one speak like this in real life. In manga, you would typically see this used by a noble princess, old man, etc.

The negative counterpart is perhaps `dictionary-form + でない`. See: [何も言うでない ! meaning and origin](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33807/5010)

Answer (score 2):

見るがいい。means "Why don't you take a look at it?"

見たほうがいい。means "You'd better take a look at it."

諦めるがいい。means "Just give up on it."

諦めたほうがいい。 means "You'd better give up on it."