# Would someone be willing to check my reading of の in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particle-の

I'm not certain why the の is in the 2nd sentence:

> 「それから、おれのくちばしやつめを見ろ。そして、よくお前**の**とくらべて見るがいい。」 
>   「鷹さん。それはあんまり無理です。」

It seems like the meaning should be "And then, often you are compared with [me] and you look good."

But if that's right, then the の seems unnecessary. (Shouldn't お前とくらべて = "you are compared with [me]?)

So, I guess the の is saying that the comparison *itself* belongs to お前?
 *e.g.*
"And then, often [there is the] comparison **of** you with [me] and you look good."
*or*
"And then, often [there is] **your** comparison with [me] and you look good.

Are either of those right?

Comment: 前文も示してください。「おれのくちばしやつめを見ろ。そして、よくお前のとくらべて見るがいい。」ですよね。「そして、それらを(=俺のくちばしや爪を)、お前のとよく比べて見るがいい。」ってことですよね。前文を書いてくれ**なくちゃ** 、「くらべてみる」の目的語が何かわから**ない**。*If* you do *not* show the previous sentence, we can *not* know what's the object of くらべてみる.

Comment: Fair point. I didn't want to clutter the post with a wall of text (I thought it would be distracting). I assumed that "[me]" would be enough for the purpose of recognizing an implied comparison to the speaker. (Unless I was wrong, and お前 _isn't_ being compared to the speaker). I'll include more context next time.

Comment: Added the previous and succeeding sentences. That's gonna be my new rule when I post (unless you think I need to go further).

Comment: user3856370さんの回答が完全だと思います。（+１）　「よくお前のとくらべて見るがいい。」は、一般には、「よくお前の**もの**とくらべてみるといい。」という文から「もの」が省略されたものです。日本語では、文脈から判断して「もの」が何をさしているか明確な場合（ここでは「くちばしや爪」）は、例文のようによく省略されます。

Comment: ^ macky `完全` ? 「俺の(もの)を お前の(もの) ***と***くらべてみろ」ですよ？　"Compare mine ***with*** yours" ですよ？ "You should have a good *look at yours* " じゃないでしょう。"Look at my beak and nails. And compare them (= **mine** ) **with yours** carefully." じゃないんですか。鷹は夜だかに「俺のを見ろ」って言ってんです。「お前のを見ろ」って言ってんじゃないんです。前文がないと、 **誰の**ものをお前のと比べてみろ、って言ってるかわかんないです。

Comment: @Chocolate: I also think the **comparison** is implied in the translation. ひ弱なお前のくちばしや爪を良く見ろ！（とっても俺のくちばしや爪に[敵]｛かな｝う叶う訳がないだろうが）。

Comment: ^ Huh?  It's saying "Look at mine. And you should compare them with yours." 「俺のを見ろ。そしてお前のと比べろ。」. It's not the same as "Look at mine. And you should have a good look at yours."

Comment: And, saying 「もの」が**省略された**ものです is inaccurate; the の's in 俺**の**と比べろ and 俺**の**ものと比べろ are not the same thing, to begin with. The former is 準体助詞, eg 彼女*の* hers, 大きい*の*が欲しい I want the big one, さっき来た*の*は誰？ (examples from 明鏡国語辞典), whereas the latter is the genitive case particle (属格助詞).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

お前の stands on its own and means 'yours'. The の doesn't join お前 to the following words as you seem to suggest. So お前のとくらべる is 'compare (mine) with yours', where 'mine' is implicit.

For the verb+がいい part have a read of [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36714/the-meaning-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%84).

verb-て見る is 'try doing verb' in this case (see @chocolate's comment below for why 見る is in kanji)

Finally (unless context suggests otherwise) I'd be more inclined to think that よく meant 'well' rather than 'often'.

Maybe I'd translate the whole thinks as something like:

> You should carefully/thoroughly compare (mine) with yours.

where よく is carefully/thoroughly, or some word that implies that the comparison is done 'well'.

Thanks to @chocolate for helping to improve my answer.

Comment: So the の isn't indicating a specific possession since it isn't followed by a noun, right? It's just "of you/yours." Therefore, a more literal translation would be **"And then, [it is] nicely [done] [that] you compare yours with [mine] and to look [is] good."** Or more creatively, **"You should take a good look, and compare yours with mine."** Right?

Comment: `You should have a good look at yours.` -- The context was added: 「おれのくちばしやつめを見ろ。そして、よくお前のとくらべて見るがいい。」 So it means 「そして、 それらを(=俺のくちばしや爪を)、お前の**と**よく比べてみるがいい。」"And, you should try comparing them (= mine) **with** yours carefully." になりません？

Comment: @Chocolate Without context I was guessing a situation that might have gone like: "Your skills are rubbish". "Yeah? Well you should take a good look at yours". In this case the comparison is implied. Possibly I extrapolated a bit too much, but I still think your translation and mine have very similar meaning. I'm happy to change my translation to something more literal if you think it will improve the answer.

Comment: I think you should at least show the basic grammatical structure of this sentence to the OP by pointing out that 1) くらべてみる used here is 「くらべて+ subsidiary verb みる」 **"try comparing", not "compare and look"** (宮沢賢治 often writes subsidiary verbs/補助動詞 in Kanji, eg 飛んで行く, 出て来ない) since OP is misreading that part as "**compare** yours with [mine] and to **look**..." "You should **take a** good **look , and compare**...", 2) the object of the くらべてみる is not お前の/yours but 俺のくちばしや爪 which is omitted/implied, since OP is misreading this part, too, as "compare **yours with mine**".

Comment: @Chocolate thanks for your comments. I've  made some updates.