# Help with understanding the following sentence: 考えても見るがいい

Tags: translation, particle-が, particle-も, interpretation

So, again, the sentence is

> 考えても見るがいい

and the provided English is

> Just think about it.

([context](https://youtu.be/vdsNfdWirtk?t=70))

I don't understand quite anything about the sentence. I know of the てみる structure but I don't really think it is related. If it was just 「考えてもいい」 it would make sense, even though the English version is (I think) more "assertive".

Edit:

It turns out that the use of verb + がいい is a form of commanding or invitation, as was suggested in the comments, and explained at [The meaning of ～がいい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36714/45489)

With this in mind, I found a discussion about what I think is an equivalent expression on [yahoo](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13202487918):

> 考えてもみてほしい

Here the answer describes the meaning of the phrase as follows:

> 考えてもみてほしいは、考えるということを有意義、有意味なこととして希望、推奨している表現です。

So I think I understand that this is an invitation to think about something, with the implied nuance that doing so may prove to be beneficial/useful, but I still don't understand how this stems from the usage of 〜ても〜

Comment: Your source leads to an hour-long video, where we're expected to fish out that one line? Please link to the location or provide a timestamp, but also it'd be preferable if you wrote out the entire sentence, as links may not be valid in the future.

Comment: The following may clarify your doubts. [The meaning of ～がいい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36714/45489)

Comment: @Jimmy I thought I copied the link with the timestamp, I'll correct it as soon as possible. I think I'll also have time to transcribe the context at that time

Comment: @sundowner thank you, I didn't realize there should have been a nominalizer for the がいい structure to be correct, and that it had in fact this other ordering meaning. I actually managed to find an answer on the internet thanks to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already understand 考えてみるがいい is a way to say "Try thinking!" This `attributive-form + がいい` is a pompous, arrogant and old-fashioned way of making an imperative, and you would hear this said by an emperor, a prophet, a dragon and such (in fiction).

- [<動詞の辞書形>　+　がよい ―　How is this allowed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/5010)
- [Plain Verb followed by がよい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64661/5010)

Next, what's the difference between these two?

- 考えてみるがいい (or 考えてみろ / 考えてみなさい / etc)
- 考えて**も**みるがいい (or 考えて**も**みろ / 考えて**も**みなさい / etc)

The role of this も is hard to explain, but I can at least say this has nothing to do with ても meaning "even though" as in 走っても間に合わない. Instead, this も is here to add a certain type of exclamatory feeling... something along the lines of "I'm serious", "come on", "at least in this case" or "already (as in 'stop it already')". I believe this is a type of exclamatory-も:

- [Odd use of も has me stumped 「ソウルにいるのも今夜きりです」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010)
- [What is an emphatic particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58843/5010)
- [Usage of も in そんなこともないけど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51841/5010)

Practically speaking, I think you can regard `te-form + も + みろ/みなさい/etc` as a set phrase.